# ANTLR IDL Grammar

Tags: syntax, antlr, grammar, idl

Using ANTLR I am trying to create a very simple IDL-style grammar. Here is what I have so far.

```
grammar idl;

data_type 
 : 'DataType' ID LCURLY attribute_list RCURLY
 ;

modifier 
 : 'public'
 ;

primitive 
 : 'byte'
 | 'short'
 | 'int'
 | 'float'
 | 'double'
 ;

attribute 
 : modifier primitive ID END
 ;

attribute_list
 : attribute+
 ;

ID  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

LCURLY  : '{'
 ;

RCURLY  : '}'
 ;

END : ';'
 ;
```

This does not seem to work when I run the debugger over 'data_type' however. It just halts when it reaches the 'attribute_list'. Changing 'attribute_list' to just 'attribute' works fine but obviously I want one-or-more attributes, not just one.

Thanks

Comment: running a manual test with the input string `"DataType fooId { public int x; public byte y; }"` produces the expected parse tree. What is your test input? And why have you defined `modifier` and `primitive` as parser rules? They are better suited as lexer rules instead.

Comment: Bart... Thank for the response. It's quite odd. I have run this exact input string against the grammar many times in debug. As I step through the parsing it consistently stops once it enters into any form of recursion (i.e. attribute+). 

As for why I have defined modifier and primitive as parser rules... I have no good reason for this.

Comment: An update here. I threw all of this into a java project and ran the generated parser over the input string. Everything parses fine. So, I guess that my issue is either related to me using the ANTLRWorks debug tool incorrectly or there is a legitimate bug with it? More than likely that the former is true I'm sure.

Thanks for the help though Bart.

Comment: either a bug or not using the debugger from ANTLRWorks properly, I can't help you with it since I don't use ANTLRWorks. I suggest you post a message to the [ANTLR mailing list](http://www.antlr.org/mailman/listinfo/antlr-interest). Good luck!